# How do I parse multi-part POST request using Angular and Express, with additional inputs?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I can parse my multi-part data, but not my regular input information that goes along with the form. I have a word document being uploaded, which I can parse fine, but I can't grab the information from the input text types. I post the request to the server, and it gets there, except the request object is very weird because Angularjs does not support multi-part submission natively, and I had to post the requesting as an angular.identity. I am using busboy-connect to parse the multi part information, so my method looks a little like this:

```
  req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
//this code parses the file
}
```

However, whenever I try I try req.name, or req.param(name), I keep getting either undefined or null. Is there a way I can switch between bodyParser and busboy? I've printed out the request as JSON at the bottom.

Cheers

```
{ _writableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     objectMode: false,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     decodeStrings: true,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     sync: true,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     buffer: [] },
  writable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { unpipe: [Function: onunpipe],
     drain: [Function],
     error: [Function: onerror],
     close: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onclose] },
     finish: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onfinish] } },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  _done: false,
  _parser: 
   { _needDrain: false,
     _pause: false,
     _cb: undefined,
     _nparts: 0,
     _boy: [Circular],
     parser: 
      { _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _bparser: [Object],
        _headerFirst: undefined,
        _dashes: 0,
        _parts: 0,
        _finished: false,
        _realFinish: false,
        _isPreamble: true,
        _justMatched: false,
        _firstWrite: true,
        _inHeader: true,
        _part: undefined,
        _cb: undefined,
        _ignoreData: false,
        _partOpts: {},
        _pause: false,
        _hparser: [Object] } },
  opts: 
   { headers: 
      { host: 'localhost:3000',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'content-length': '44520',
        accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36',
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyUi7ZbB4IU8PXkzm',
        referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6,es;q=0.4',
        cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AZpb0Vg74dgR-1iz3-bXPKhKnZyC9UY4U.uPvsAKswVQStlkMkDAv%2F%2BBIVA1rFzPC63xdZT5b7dnk' } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the 'field' event as well to catch non-file types. See the examples [here](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#examples).